# AngularJS - $$ChildScope Vs $$childHead && $$childTail

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

`angular.element($0).scope()` gives `$$ChildScope`, `$$childHead` and `$$childTail` as members.

On debugging, `$$childHead` and `$$childTail` shows the immediate child scopes.

[image]

What does `$$ChildScope` signify?

Comment: if current running scope has child element with its own scope then that function will be return an `object` again.otherwise it will return `null`